# Change "primefaces-themeName" to "primefaces_themeName"

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I try to change the folder name `primefaces-myTheme` to `primefaces_myTheme` but when I run the application, It throws an exception

```
<i>Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading css, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-myTheme" library </i>
```

It keeps looking for `primefaces-myTheme`.

Is it posible to change the folder name `primefaces-myTheme` to another folder name?

I´m using primefaces 5.2.

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: I need to change it, because it´s a requirement of the project.

Comment: 'requirement of the project' is not a use case but a specific use case can be a requirement of the project though. To me this sounds that someone else has a problem for which they think changing this is the solution (no-one ever needed to, so it is very, very rare). Consequently the question remains, **_why_** is this a requirement of the project? And "The _architect_ (or team lead) told me so" is not a good answer ;-)

Comment: You could also try writing a resource handler. But again, I wouldn't bother and just go with the convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible because it's hard-coded: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/renderkit/HeadRenderer.java#L89

But you can overwrite the HeadRenderer (see: [How to register a custom renderer in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763481/how-to-register-a-custom-renderer-in-jsf))